# Difference between Googlecloud's pub/sub, socket, ipc, etc

Tags: node.js, socket.io, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using node.js server and GCloud. What is exactly the GCloud's pub/sub? Does it work like socket or tcp? My server is using socket.io and node-ipc for communicating, can GCloud's pub/sub be the alternative?

Answer (score 4):

PubSub is a messaging service. These allow asynchronous communication between two applications; one "publishes a message" to a message service and then some other process reads that message from the message service at a later time - seconds, minutes, or hours later. The application that published the message does not need to "stay connected".

That's really useful for scalable and reliable communication between applications - but quite different from socket-based communication which is point-to-point between a client and server process. Implementing request/response type communications is difficult over a messaging service - "send and forget" is the usual model. As @komarkovich noted, a message can also be received by many applications if that is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) is an asynchronous  publish/subscribe messaging service. 
Publisher creates and sends messages to a topic. Subscriber creates a subscription to a topic to receive messages from it. Communication can be one-to-many, many-to-one, and many-to-many.

Pub/Sub has two [endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#endpoints):

- Publisher: Any application that can make HTTPS requests to googleapis.com.
- Subscriber:

  - Pull subscriber: Also any application that can make HTTPS requests to googleapis.com.
  - Push subscriber: Webhook endpoints that can accept POST requests over HTTPS.

You can check the [Cloud Pub/Sub Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) and review the example for Node.js to get you started using Google Cloud Pub/Sub API.