# Socket.io vs Google Cloud Pub Sub

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, socket.io, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm developing website where people can write articles collaboratively but I can't decide whether to do it with socket.io or use Google Pub Sub. I have looked through both and Pub Sub seems to be great for scalability but how bad is latency for example ? Is it sufficient for collaborative editing ?

Comment: Did you consider streaming update instead of PubSub notification?

Comment: I have, but it's it just for cloud storage data ? I'm saving text in mysql and articles have a fixed length

Comment: The principle is to open a session on Cloud Run, a websocket, and then to push, in this channel the updates of the documents. i'm not talking about stream upload in GCS, only web native capability.

Comment: This might help you comprehend the difference between using Pub Sub and socket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643022/difference-between-googleclouds-pub-sub-socket-ipc-etc

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Pub/Sub latency could work for your use case (typically, messages are delivered within hundreds of ms of being published). However, Pub/Sub is typically used for server-based application-to-application messaging. Using Pub/Sub from a web client may be challenging, since there is no native client library available; you may find better luck with socket.io.